# NSURLConnection Response not being added to Mutable array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

Whats wrong with this code below in my header file I have a property:

`@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *imgArray;`

When I view the `NSLog` at the end the "imgArray" is always empty. I am trying to pull multiple images in a `UIImageView` subclass to make animated "gif". The issue is the array is always empty so its not adding any images because the array is empty.

In my `.m` file:

```
@implementation AnimatedOverlay

BOOL isValid;

@synthesize imgArray;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    [self startAnimatingWithFrame:frame];
}
return self;
}

-(void) startAnimatingWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDate *hourAgo = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:-3600 sinceDate:today];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH"];
NSString *hourString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH"];
NSString *hourString2 = [dateFormat stringFromDate:hourAgo];

imgArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
    NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/Conus/RadarImg/southeast_%@_%@%i8_N0Ronly.gif",dateString,hourString,i]];
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileUrl];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,NSData * data,NSError * error) {
         if ([data length] >0 && error == nil){
             UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
             if(image!=nil){
                 [imgArray addObject:image];

             }
         }else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil){
             NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded.");
         }else if (error != nil){
             NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
         }
     }];
}
NSLog(@"%@",imgArray);

self.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:imgArray];
self.animationDuration = 1.0f;
self.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[self startAnimating];
}
```

Comment: It is being added. But it's asynchronous so it is being added long after you log the array.

Comment: so how can I solve this problem? do I use non-asynchronous?

Comment: What problem (besides the logging) are you having?

Comment: i added my full code and edited my post above with a better question.

Comment: An image is download, then you perform animation. Or all images are download, then you perform animation?

Comment: All images need to be downloaded first then animated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/Conus/RadarImg/southeast_%@_%@%i8_N0Ronly.gif",dateString,hourString,i]];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileUrl];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,NSData * data,NSError * error) {
     if ([data length] >0 && error == nil){
         UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
         if(image!=nil){
             [imgArray addObject:image];

         }
     }else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil){
         NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded.");
     }else if (error != nil){
         NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
     }
//Use your imgArray inside the completion handler block, right now you are using it outside the block 

NSLog(@"%@",imgArray);

self.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:imgArray];
self.animationDuration = 1.0f;
self.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[self startAnimating];
}];
}
```

Hope this will work for you.